# How to manage a deeply nested view with react, redux and react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux

Say, I want to have urls like this in my app:

```
/user/orders/1/details/payment
```

Which represents a view that shows details view for an order with id 1 and the active tab is `payment`.

This functionality is implemented except connecting it to router.

In a tutorial I see this example:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

But I suppose that I want all urls to map to the root `App` and then their values mapped to respective redux store variable and inside the `App` I would decide what to show depending on the values of store that are extracted from the current url.

What's an example of using such a scenario?

Comment: looks as though you want something like this? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params

Comment: try using `react-router-v4`, it's much more better that previous versions.

Comment: Beats me if I understand what is the question.